# Visual Studio v15.4.1 - undo feature [Ctrl]+[Click] "go to definition"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Prior to Visual Studio v15.4.1 `[Ctrl] + [Mouse Left Click]` would highlight (equivalent to double-clicking), which made copy and paste a convenient process.

- `F12`: the keyboard shortcut for "Go to definition". ** this is what it does now **
- `double-click`: selects / highlights the entire word.  ** this is what it used to do **

> Is there a way to revert the `[Ctrl] + [Click]` shortcut to go back to how it used to be?

Comment: Change in Tools-> options->Keyboard the shortcut, but don't know exactly which one.

Comment: @Lord_Curdin it's a mouse shortcut, not keyboard.

Comment: @Lord_Curdin --- oh you helped me find the setting though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Lord_Curdin - I ended up searching for the keyword `"mouse"` in the Visual Studio Options and found it.

You can disable the setting by going to:

```
→ Tools
   → Options
      → Text Editor
         → General
            [ ] Enable mouse click to perform G̲o to Definition
```

[image]

Comment: if you have installed the Productivity Power Tools you need to disabe the CTRL Goto Extension